# How to install Wine 5 on elementary OS 5.1 Hera?

Tags: release-hera, wine, install

Hi guys here is Question and answer: how to install latest stable Wine 5 for elementary OS 5.1 Hera?

Comment: why add this?: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport

Comment: Welcome to elementary OS SE. Your participation is much appreciated. Please let me inform you that self-answered questions are welcomed here but you should create an answer for answer, do not include the answer in the question. Also, the we love detailed answers. For instance, you can explain why you are executing those commands. Please read, [Can I answer my own question?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), take a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) Have a nice day!

Comment: It is for FAudio support

Comment: With adding the repositories I get an error: "The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hera Release' does not have a Release file." Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Still have an error: `The following packages have unmet dependencies: winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~bionic)`

Comment: depurando antes elementary, es excelente, gracias!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386  

wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key 

sudo apt-key add winehq.key  

sudo apt install software-properties-common  

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport  

sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'  

sudo apt update && sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```